# Mapping GPS application with off-line maps

Tags: gps

I'm looking for any suggestions for a Ubuntu mapping program with gps similar to e.g. Delorme Topo (can  be similar to their older versions) that comes with and uses an off-line topographical map database.

Answer (score 0):

GpsPrune is an application for viewing, editing and converting coordinate data from GPS systems. Basically it's a tool to let you play with your GPS data after you get home from your trip.

Some example uses of GpsPrune include cleaning up tracks by deleting wayward points - either recorded by error or by unintended detours. It can also be used to compare and combine tracks, convert to and from various formats, compress tracks, export data to Google Earth, or to analyze data to calculate distances, altitudes and so on.

https://activityworkshop.net/software/gpsprune/

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please expand it.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend [TangoGPS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TangoGPS)I have used my Asus Eeepc - it does not do turn by turn but it does cache maps for use off line and it indicates where you are.

Once you understand the format you can create a text file from   [openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) that you can save so your route is pre-indicated by a green line. Worth a look if you can put up with its idiosyncrasies.